# Returning an array of 2D arrays in C

Tags: c

First, I'll admit this is homework but it has been around six years since I last programmed in C and ever since I have been only programming in Python and Java.

I want to generate successor 2D arrays to a 2D array for example:

```
[1][2][3] 
[4][5][6] 
[7][8][ ]
```

For the 2D array above, the successor 2D arrays would be:

```
[1][2][3]
[4][5][6]
[7][ ][8]
```

and

```
[1][2][3]
[4][5][ ]
[7][8][6]
```

This wouldn't be a problem if I just placed the code for this in a main() method.

However I want to separate the code for this part and encapsulate it in a function and just call it when I need it. In other words, I want to generate both arrays from inside a function and return both of them.

In C this is isn't as straightforward because I can't make a function that can pass an array of 2D arrays.

I have some ideas like

1. return a struct with a 2d array and next variable that is a pointer to another successor 2D array (I want to process all the successor arrays in a loop).
2. create a global pointer where I will point the head to the first struct, which in turn points to the next succesor 2d array and so on.

But I am not really confident which one to try. Looking for other helpful leads.

Comment: It's not clear at all what "successor" means. The examples are not doing it for me.

Comment: Terminology nitpick: C doesn't have methods, it has procedures and functions.

Comment: What makes you think that you can not pass an array of 2D arrays ? It is perfectly straightforward. What have you tried ?

Comment: @cdhowie, oh yeah :) changed it now.

Comment: Looks to me like a slid puzzle. Maybe you should add the tag homework to your question.

Comment: @Paul R not pass an array of 2D arrays but rather return an array of 2D arrays from a function.

Comment: @Nobody, yeah I did mention it was homework :)

Comment: @Jeune: you can also return an array of 2D arrays quite simply - again: what have you tried, and what was the problem ?

Comment: @Paul R Oh beforehand I was thinking of "fitting" a 2D array into a cell of a single array. I know it's silly. I was still probably thinking in OOP mode where I would let the array be an instance variable of an object and where I would return a list of objects with arrays in them. Anyway, it's much clearer now that the concept of a 3D array has been suggested ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return an array of 2D arrays:

```
int*** getArrayOf2DArrays(int num_arrays, int rows_per_array, int cols_per_array)
{
    int*** arr = malloc(num_arrays * sizeof(int**));
    // check that arr isn't null

    for(int i = 0; i < num_arrays; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = malloc(rows_per_array * sizeof(int*));
        // again, check result

        for(int j = 0; j < rows_per_array; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = malloc(cols_per_array * sizeof(int));
            // yet again, check result

            // NOT necessary, but if you want to initialize the values
            // here, you could. Either use memset or:
            for(int k = 0; k < cols_per_array; k++)
                arr[i][j][k] = 0;
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

And then you can access it with `arr[array_number][row][col]`. Make sure to free it when you're done (similar process, only in reverse):

```
void freeArrayOf2DArrays(int*** arr, int num_arrays, int rows_per_array)
{
    // sanity checks here
    for(int i = 0; i < num_arrays; i++)
    {
        // and here
        for(int j = 0; j < rows_per_array)
            // and here
            free(arr[i][j]);
        free(arr[i]);
    }

    free(arr);
}
```

And of course you can just pass this pointer around to any of your functions using a `int***` data type.

Comment: Nope not just ONE 2D array, I want to return an array of 2D arrays :)

Comment: Ah ok, well then that's just one more level. Let me adjust this.

Comment: By the way, in most circles an array of 2D arrays is also known as a 3D array (unless each array is a different size, in which case it's a 3D jagged array).

Answer (score 1):

An array of 2D arrays is just a 3D array, so you can pass them the same way as parameters/return values. Since you have a fixed size in 2 dimensions, it may be a lot easier to just use a int* as type, and treat it as a 3D array